# Rest Search by Result Source

Tags: search, search-results, rest

I have defined a Managed Result Source at the Search Application level of my SharePoint Online tenant and am attempting to run this search using the /_api/search/query REST endpoint.  I know this search result works because I am using it well on my sites using the Query Results web parts which are configured using this same Result Source.  I captured the ID of my Result source from the URL.

```
../_layouts/15/searchadmin/EditResultSource.aspx?
level=tenant&sourceid=d0aa2c2e%2D7709%2D46f1%2D835a%2D244f483e4b0e
```

I then place that ID in the following REST URL in Fiddler

```
 ../_api/search/query?
sourceid='d0aa2c2e%2D7709%2D46f1%2D835a%2D244f483e4b0e'
```

The JSON returned is a not a list of the specific content types which I am searching for.

Do I need to add more to the REST query to get it to behave like the Search Results Web Parts do?

Comment: Does your custom result source contain a query transform that filters on content type(s)? The connection between your result source and the "specific content types" is unclear.

Comment: Also, have you tried using dashes instead of the URL encoded equivalent? From the MSDN documentation: http://server/_api/search/query?querytext='sharepoint'&sourceid='8413cd39-2156-4e00-b54d-11efd9abdb89' Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163876(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: I found the issue.  I was not submitting the security cookie with my requests.